# Multiple Nested async AJAX calls and order of returned data

Tags: ajax, json, asynchronous, nested, synchronous

First time poster here. I've found some great answers to other issues I've come across but this one has stumped me and I'm not sure the best way to go about it. I've done some searching but haven't found anything that looks like it is a solution.

I am building a table that is a basic BOM display. The function takes the desired part ID and spaces (just used to indent the results for readability) and checks each result for any child parts by calling itself again and so on.

This works great if I set ASYNC to *false* and I get the desired results but I thought there might be a way to make this asynchronous and achieve the same results in a shorter amount of time.

And yes, I will modify it so it's not updating the DOM with each call. I will change it to a variable so there is only one call in the end!

Any help appreciated.

```
/*******************************************************************
FUNCTION -  Traverse the BOM     
            Check each PID for child parts          
********************************************************************/   
function traverse_bom(search_term, spaces) {     
    spaces += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $.ajax({
        //async: false, 
        url: 'spec_collector_ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  { data_retrieve: "database_query",
                 table: "Product_Structure",
                 order: "ORDER BY COMPRT_02",
                 search: search_term},                 
        success: function(data2) 
        {       
            // If there is data, then print it out to a table     
            if (data2 != 0) 
            {               
                // Iterate through each entry and list the results
                $.each(data2, function(i2,item2) 
                {      
                    // print the BOM entry info
                    $('#table_bom tbody:last').append( '<tr><td>' + spaces + item2.COMPRT_02 + '</td><td>' + item2.QTYPER_02 + '</td></tr>');

                    // Check for children under this part
                    traverse_bom(item2.COMPRT_02, spaces);                     
                });
            } 

            else
            {
            }
        },
        // Error handling
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // Print error message for debugging
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    }); 
};
```

Comment: have you thought about implementing a queue to contain your ajax calls?  you might be experiencing timing issues on the callbacks when you have async turned on.

Comment: With the ASYNC calls, each call to the _ajax.php file that queries the database can be faster or slower than the previous one so there is no guarantee that they will all come back in order. I will see if queues are the answer.

Comment: I've decided instead to modify the SQL statement to retrieve all of the BOM elements in one AJAX call rather than one AJAX call for each BOM element. Much more efficient and less work on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [async = false](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Ajax/jQuery.ajax&redirect=no#jQuery-ajax-settings) during recursion of the calls making your subsequent calls synchronous and wont screw up your order.

For Example:

```
/*******************************************************************
FUNCTION -  Traverse the BOM     
            Check each PID for child parts          
********************************************************************/   
function traverse_bom(search_term, spaces, synchronous) {
    //if synchronous is null default to asynchronous 
    if(synchronous == null) { synchronous = false; }

    spaces += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $.ajax({
        //async: false, 
        url: 'spec_collector_ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: !synchronous, //Not synchronous
        data:  { data_retrieve: "database_query",
                 table: "Product_Structure",
                 order: "ORDER BY COMPRT_02",
                 search: search_term},                 
        success: function(data2) 
        {       
            // If there is data, then print it out to a table     
            if (data2 != 0) 
            {               
                // Iterate through each entry and list the results
                $.each(data2, function(i2,item2) 
                {      
                    // print the BOM entry info
                    $('#table_bom tbody:last').append( '<tr><td>' + spaces + item2.COMPRT_02 + '</td><td>' + item2.QTYPER_02 + '</td></tr>');

                    // Check for children under this part
                    // This is where we set synchronous to true, inside the recursion.
                    traverse_bom(item2.COMPRT_02, spaces, true); 
                });
            } 

            else
            {
            }
        },
        // Error handling
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // Print error message for debugging
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    }); 
};
```